# how to display the sum of values from two groups of input - ajax

Tags: html, ajax, input, sum

I wanted to sum up the values from group name='s' and group name='v'
when radio button clicked, they call the function pieces(str, str2)

the problem is, it seems like the execution of ajax here comes at a time. cant get the value of 1st group when 2nd group is activated, vise versa

these are the inputs

```
    <input type='radio' id='1' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='6'>6
    <input type='radio' id='2' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='12'>12
    <input type='radio' id='3' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='24'>24


    <input type='radio' id='11' name='v' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='50'>Yes
    <input type='radio' id='12' name='v' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='0'>No


    <div id='txtHint'>Sum will display here</div>
```

here's my script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#btn').click(function(){
                        var str1=$('input:radio[name=s]').val();
                        var str2=$('input:radio[name=v]').val();
                        pieces(str1,str2);
                    });
                    });

                function pieces(str1, str2)

                {                   
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

                      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                      }

                    else
                      {// code for IE6, IE5
                      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                      }

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                      {
                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {               document.getElementById(txtHint).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }

                      }


                    xmlhttp.open('GET','url.php?var1='+str1+'&var2='+str2,true);

                    xmlhttp.send();

                }
```

heres the link page at ajax code

```
    <?php

    $s = $_GET['s'];
    $v = $_GET['v'];

    if($s == 6 && $v == 50)
        echo"value";

    else if($s == 6 && $v == 0)
        echo"value";

    else if($s == 12 $v == 50)
        echo"value";

    else if($s == 12 $v == 0)
        echo"value";


    else if($s == 24 $v == 50)
            echo"value";

    else if($s == 24 $v == 50)
            echo"value";

    ?>
```

please help. newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the answer for my own question. I'll post it here for the benefits of those who will come up with this same question.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    function calc()
    {

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }


      if (document.form.value1[0].checked)
        s = 6;

      else if (document.form.value1[1].checked)
        s = 12;

      else if (document.form.value1[2].checked)
        s = 24;

      if (document.form.value2[0].checked)
        v = 5;

      else  if (document.form.value2[1].checked)
        v = 0;

      document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML="Calculating...";
      queryPath = "CalcServ.php?value1="+s+"&value2="+v;

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

          document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET",queryPath);
      xmlhttp.send();


    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div width="320">
          <center>
            <form name="form">
            <font size="4"><strong>PHP/AJAX Calculator</strong></font><br/><br/>
               <input  onclick='calc(this.value);' id="6" type="radio" name="value1" value="6">6<br/>
               <input  onclick='calc(this.value);' id="12" type="radio" name="value1" value="12">12<br/>
               <input  onclick='calc(this.value);' id="24" type="radio" name="value1" value="24">24<br/>

               <br/>
                 <input  onclick='calc(this.value);' id="y" type="radio" name="value2" value="yes">yes<br/>
                 <input  onclick='calc(this.value);' id="n" type="radio" name="value2" value="no">no<br/>
             </form>

        <strong><font size="4" color="blue"><span id="resp"></span></font></strong>
        </center>
        </div>
          </body>

    </html>
```

and here's the page to be call

```
    <?php

    if ($_REQUEST["value1"] == "6" && $_REQUEST["value2"] == "5")
        $sum = 6 + 5;

    else if ($_REQUEST["value1"] == "6" && $_REQUEST["value2"] == "0")
        $sum = 6;

    else if ($_REQUEST["value1"] == "12" && $_REQUEST["value2"] == "5")
        $sum = 12 + 5;

    else if ($_REQUEST["value1"] == "12" && $_REQUEST["value2"] == "0")
        $sum = 12;

    else if ($_REQUEST["value1"] == "24" && $_REQUEST["value2"] == "5")
        $sum = 24 + 5;

    else if ($_REQUEST["value1"] == "24" && $_REQUEST["value2"] == "0")
        $sum = 24;


    echo $sum;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- In your `onclick` of an `input` element, you call `pieces` with one argument while that functions expects and uses two arguments (`str` and `str2`): it needs both to call the correct URL in the ajax call. It's therefore better to do the following instead of calling `pieces` immediately: create a function that gathers the values for `str` and `str2` by looking at the currently selected options in group `s` and group `v`. You can then call `pieces` with both values.
- Have you checked that your ajax call is correct? Does a request actually reach the server? It's common these days to rely on a JavaScript library to perform the ajax calls but if you're ajax code is correct and works in multiple browsers then that's fine too.
- Finally, you're returning a response from the ajax call but it is never used in the JavaScript code. You need to read the ajax response and put the value somewhere in the web page (also using JavaScript).

Comment: if i call function s(s) for group s
and call function v(v) for group v
how can i call function two(s,v)
so i can get the values from those two function.
sorry im a newbie here :)

Comment: You can create a function `two(this)` that is called in `onclick`. The function `two` will have to get the values for `s` and `v` from the HTML and perform the ajax call. You can then display the result where you want it to be displayed. So this means you have to get/modify the HTML values yourself instead of using `this.value`.